# Passing validation as session flash data in Laravel: Serialization of Closure is not allowed

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Taking the following class:

```
class SessionHelper
{
    public static function GetViewModel()
    {
        return unserialize( Session::get( 'viewModel' ) );
    }

    public static function StoreViewModel( $object )
    {
        return Session::flash( 'viewModel', serialize( $object ) );
    }
}
```

Imagine I have a registration controller method with this in:

```
public function PostRegister()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $values,
        $rules,
        $messages
    );

    if( $validation->fails() )
    {
        $viewModel->User->Password = NULL;
        $viewModel->Validation = $validation->messages();                
        SessionHelper::StoreViewModel( $viewModel );

        return Redirect::action( "AuthenticationController@GetRegister" );
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
      Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed 

      Open: C:\xampp\htdocs\...\app\models\Helpers\SessionHelper.php  

5.    public static function GetViewModel()
6.    {
7.        return unserialize( Session::get( 'viewModel' ) );
8.    }
9.    
10.    public static function StoreViewModel( $object )
11.    {
12.        return Session::flash( 'viewModel', serialize( $object ) );
13.    }
14.}
```

I want to be able to pass the validation object over into another controller method using the Redirect::action functions... Any ideas how I do this?

```
public function GetRegister()
{
    if( !$viewModel = SessionHelper::GetViewModel() )
    {
        $viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    }        

    return View::make( "Authentication/Register", ModelHelper::Prepare( $viewModel ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably will have to serialize only the array of messages:

```
$viewModel->Validation = $validation->messages()->all();
```

Comment: And then the withErrors isn't going to work is it... Okay, i'll just put up with re-declaring bits of code for now